# PHP Parse issue

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am trying to setup my PHP site in my hosting server which is made from Codeigniter 2.2.0. Everything is fine only `$end_date = $end_date ?: $start_date;` this line of code generate a parse error -saying Parse error:

```
syntax error, unexpected ':' .
```

My hosting server php version is 5.2. How can I avoid this error?

Answer (score 2):

In PHP, shorthand ternary operator is [only available](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php#example-122) since version 5.3.

Quote:

> Since PHP 5.3, it is possible to leave out the middle part of the
>   ternary operator. Expression expr1 ?: expr3 returns expr1 if expr1
>   evaluates to TRUE, and expr3 otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
$end_date = (!empty($end_date)) ? $end_date : $start_date;
```

Comment: thanks. Would you please tell me what is difference between of two lines.

Comment: There is no need to use [`empty()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php). Evaluating `$end_date` in boolean context (as it happens when it is the first operand of the [ternary conditional operator](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php#language.operators.comparison.ternary)) is [the same as `! empty($end_date)`](http://php.net/manual/en/types.comparisons.php).

Comment: @Treadstone there is [no difference between `$end_date` and `! empty($end_date)` in this context](http://php.net/manual/en/types.comparisons.php).

Comment: @axiac if, for example, `$end_date = '&nbsp;';`the `!empty()` check is useful

Comment: `empty('&nbsp;') === FALSE`. Compare the columns `empty()` and `boolean: if($x)` from the first table displayed in the ["Comparisons of $x with PHP functions" page](http://php.net/manual/en/types.comparisons.php). `if ($x)` (or `$x ? ... : ...`) is the same as `if (! empty($x))` for any value of `$x`.

Answer (score 0):

local and host PHP versions were differents.

This code solved in booth.

```
$end_date = (!empty($end_date)) ? $end_date : $start_date;
```

Comment: There is no need to use [`empty()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php). Evaluating `$end_date` in boolean context (as it happens when it is the first operand of the [ternary conditional operator](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php#language.operators.comparison.ternary)) is [the same as `! empty($end_date)`](http://php.net/manual/en/types.comparisons.php).